# algorithm performance with insufficient input

Tags: algorithms

Generally speaking, an algorithm takes some inputs and provides some output. I would like to understand how the algorithm performs when the inputs are incomplete for various real-world reasons. Are there any papers on this issue?

Comment: This seems too broad and open-ended to be a good fit here.  An algorithm can do anything it wants, so the answer will probably depend on what particular algorithm you are using.  Do you have a specific problem you are trying to solve?  Can you edit your question to focus it on a specific problem you have right now, and describe your situation and what you're trying to accomplish in concrete terms?

Comment: What does "the inputs are incomplete" mean?